# MySQL Workbench: Cloning a schema (no data) but changing the name

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Trying to use the `data export` wizard and `Data import/restore` wizard to clone a DDL structure of 2 schemas, SchemaX and SchemaY.  It is fine, but unless I am missing something, I can't rename the schemas.  I want the new Schemas to be SchemaG and SchemaH respectively.

I'm sure I'm missing something small here, but I can't seem to find a way to rename the schema to clone them, as opposed to just standing them up on a different DB with the same name, which is not what I am needing. I am wanting to clone them on the same DB just with different names.

Sorry if this is a newbie question, I've been a MSSQL DBA for years, but MySQL for far fewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alas, Changing the name of a `DATABASE` (aka "schema") is not available.

If you were copying the data, too?  First `CREATE DATABASE` for the new `dbnew`

```
mysqldump --no-create-db --routines  dbold |
     mysql -d dbnew
```

Adding `--no-data` prevents copying any data.  (This is also a handy way to get `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for all the tables.)  (If you have no data, then this option should be irrelevant.)

(Please review the options and test this before committing to Production.)

Comment: Darn. Thank you!